# how to access variables from class.as to use in a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i have a class name sample_1.as

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class sample_1 extends MovieClip {

        public var targetScene:String;

        public function sample_1() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }
}
```

and i want to access and change the targetScene string from different frames and also inside movieclips like

```
gotoAndPlay(targetScene);
or
targetScene = "MainMenuEnter";
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and easy way to have a variable like that available from any frame/class is to make it static:

```
public class sample_1 extends MovieClip {    
    public static var targetScene:String;
}
```

You can access `targetScene` from anywhere using `sample_1.targetScene`, for example:

```
sample_1.targetScene = "3";
gotoAndPlay(uint(sample_1.targetScene));
```

It's not the best method to use, especially as a project gets bigger and has more components, declaring variables static for the sake of global access can lead to a lot of spaghetti code but it's a quick 'n' dirty fix to get you started.

Comment: are you sure that there will only ever be ONE instance? try this: `var a:MovieClip = new sample_1(); var b:MovieClip = new sample_1(); trace(a); trace(b);` - both traces will return reference to separate instance (2). There will be however the same value of `targetScene` for each instance of `sample_1`.

Comment: thanks it works! can i also apply this to functions? `sample_1.backFunc();?`